# Ember.js Router v2 and injected controllers

Tags: ember.js

In the old V1 router, all controllers were injected into the router, so it was possible to do:

```
foo = App.get('router').get('applicationController').get('bar');
```

In the new V2 router, I can't seem to even do:

```
router = App.get('router')
```

Has this changed?

Has the intended design pattern changed?  Was I doing it wrong all along?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Today, you can get access to controllers from your routes (and route actions) via:

```
this.controllerFor('posts')
```

In your controllers, you declare dependencies on other controllers:

```
App.Post = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['posts']
});
```

And then, inside your controller, you can also use `this.controllerFor`.

FYI, We plan to make this.get('controllers.posts') work inside of controllers that use `needs`, which would make using dependent controllers inside of your templates straight forward.